# Fade in and out between divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have but zero appitude to code anything. I am trying to build a small simple website and am almost done but have one little issue left to solve. I know this has been asked here before and I have tried to figure out how to make there circumstance work for me but can't. I have even tried the easy jquery fade in and fade out methods but can't get the id's correct or something?
All I want to do is fade in and out between the divs when the links are clicked.
I have tried and reviewed many examples here and still can't get it to connect at all.

Any help would be appreciated.

I have three links on a page that loads three different divs into a container. Everything is on the same page and everything works great other than I can't get them to fade in and out when the links are clicked. I have no problem loading the jquery library and doing it that way if that works best.

```
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">

function showDiv(idInfo) {
  var sel = document.getElementById('divLinks').getElementsByTagName('div');
  for (var i=0; i<sel.length; i++) {
    sel[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
  document.getElementById('container'+idInfo).style.display = 'block';
}
</script>


<style type="text/css">


#container1, #container2, #container3 {
    display:none;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color: #E6E1E6

</style>



</head>

<body style="background-color: #E6E1E6">



<div id="container" style="position: fixed; width: 100%; z-index: 200;" >
    <div id="linkDiv" style="z-index: 100; position: absolute; width: 100%; text-align: center; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; margin-top: 20px;">
    <a href="#" onclick="showDiv('1');return false" style="margin-right: 10px">The Original Woman</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="showDiv('2');return false" style="margin-right: 10px; margin-left: 10px">CREDIT</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="showDiv('3');return false" style="margin-left: 10px">CONTACT</a>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- The 4 container content divs. -->
<div id="divLinks" style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
 <div id="container1" style="position: fixed; width: 100%; height: auto;" >
     <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%">
         <tr>
             <td style="width: 60%">&nbsp;</td>
             <td class="auto-style1" style="width: 40%">
             <img height="auto" src="asencio%20(7).jpg" width="100%" />&nbsp;</td>
         </tr>
     </table>
    </div>
    <div id="container2" style="position: fixed; width: 100%; height: auto;" >
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%">
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 50%">
                <img height="auto" src="mukai.jpg" width="100%" />&nbsp;</td>
                <td style="width: 50%">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
 <div id="container3" style="position: fixed; width: 100%; height: auto;" >
     <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%">
         <tr>
             <td style="width: 37%">
             <img height="auto" src="pandora_by_alifann.jpg" width="100%" />&nbsp;</td>
             <td style="width: 62%">&nbsp;</td>
         </tr>
     </table>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() { showDiv('1'); }
</script>    

</div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I can't see anything in your code (unless I missed it) that suggests that anything is fading in or out - Give me a few minutes and I'll write up an example in jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned using jQuery, this is a basic idea. Comments in code should explain what is happening. I altered the HTML a little by adding some classes and some data attributes.

```js
$("#linkDiv").on("click", "a", function(evt) { //use event bubbling so there is only one click hanlder
  evt.preventDefault(); //stop click event

  var anchor = $(this); //get the link that was clicked on

  if (anchor.hasClass("active")) { //If has the class, it is already is active, nothing to do
    return;
  }

  anchor.siblings().removeClass("active"); //find previous selectd link and unselect it
  anchor.addClass("active"); //add class to current link and select it

  var showTab = anchor.data("tab"); //read the data attribute data-tab to get item to show
  var visibleContainer = $(".tab-container:visible");
  var complete = function() { //function to call when fade out is complete
    $(showTab).stop().fadeIn(300);
  };
  if (visibleContainer.length) { //make sure w have something to hide
    $(visibleContainer).stop().fadeOut(100, complete); //if we do, fade out the element, when finished, call complete
  } else {
    complete(); //if first time, just show it
  }
}).find("a").eq(0).trigger("click"); //click on first link to load tab content.
```

```css
.tab-container {
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#container1 {
  background-color: #E60000;
}
#container2 {
  background-color: #00E100;
}
#container3 {
  background-color: #0000E6;
}
a.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="position: fixed; width: 100%; z-index: 200;">
  <div id="linkDiv" style="z-index: 100; position: absolute; width: 100%; text-align: center; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; margin-top: 20px;">
    <a href="#" style="margin-right: 10px" data-tab="#container1">The Original Woman</a>
    <a href="#" style="margin-right: 10px; margin-left: 10px" data-tab="#container2">CREDIT</a>
    <a href="#" style="margin-left: 10px" data-tab="#container3">CONTACT</a>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- The 4 container content divs. -->
<div id="divLinks" style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
  <div id="container1" class="tab-container" style="position: fixed; width: 100%; height: auto;">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%">
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 60%">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="auto-style1" style="width: 40%">
          <img height="auto" src="asencio%20(7).jpg" width="100%" />&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="container2" class="tab-container" style="position: fixed; width: 100%; height: auto;">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%">
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 50%">
          <img height="auto" src="mukai.jpg" width="100%" />&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="width: 50%">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="container3" class="tab-container" style="position: fixed; width: 100%; height: auto;">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%">
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 37%">
          <img height="auto" src="pandora_by_alifann.jpg" width="100%" />&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="width: 62%">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some quick script to do the fading, but i would suggest you to use `jQuery` for same since it will be cross-browser.

Just update your script block, and it will work, no need to change any other code

**Vanilla JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function showDiv(idInfo) {
  var sel = document.getElementById('divLinks').getElementsByTagName('div');
  for (var i=0; i<sel.length; i++) {
    sel[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
  fadeIn(document.getElementById('container'+idInfo), 20);
}

function fadeIn(element, duration) {
    var op = 0.1;  // initial opacity
    element.style.display = 'block';
    var timer = setInterval(function () {
        if (op >= 1){
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
        element.style.opacity = op;
        element.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + op * 100 + ")";
        op += op * 0.1;
        //alert("here");
    }, duration);
}

</script>
```

**Using jQuery**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript">

function showDiv(idInfo) {
  $('#divLinks div').hide(200, function(){
      //Show the clicked 
      $('#container'+idInf).fadeIn(200);
  });
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example using jQuery - Not sure what you're end product is meant to look like but this should set you on the right foot.

Here's a sample snippet of the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){           //Wait for DOM to finish loading
  $('.navigation a').click(function(){  //When the a link is clicked
    var id = $(this).attr('href');      //grab its href as the ID of the target object
    $('.hidden-content').fadeOut(500);  //Fade out all the divs that are showing
    $(id).fadeIn(500);                  //Fade in the target div

    return false;                       //Prevent the default action of the a link
  });
});
```

Check out the jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/pavkr/7vc2jj5j/

Comment: You guys are increditable!!! They don't pay you folks enough. I used one of the examples posted and it worked great. It was the vanilla version. I think I will try to use jquery though. I find it more powerfull. I'm sure you guys have posted enough to get me set up and fixed and I can't thank you enough!!

Comment: Also, I did not put my failed tries in the code I posted because I did not want you to have to try and clean my mess up. I thought that what I needed was pretty straight forward..... I'm a freeking artist and my mind just can't grasp javascript. I do ok with HTML and cut and paste... :-)

Comment: @MichaelFitzgerald, haha, we don't get paid to answer questions on SO ;)

Comment: Well you really helped me out. Should be somewhere around here that I could say thanx....